# XFCE session fails to load when launched via LightDM

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, arm

I have set up LightDM as the desktop manager on an ARM Ubuntu install (running with a chroot on an Android device) and this loads and works fine, however when I try to launch a Xfce session as a normal user I end up with a blank black screen with just the mouse (which works).

When I check logs I have LightDM outputting:

Logging to `.xsession-errors`

```
** (process:2129): WARNING **: Failed to open CK session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit was not provided by any .service files
[+302.39s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+302.39s] WARNING: Error using VT_ACTIVATE 7 on /dev/console: Invalid argument
[+302.39s] WARNING: Error using VT_WAITACTIVE 7 on /dev/console: Invalid argumen
```

And then in xsession-errors:

```
init: Unable to register as subreaper: Invalid argument
init: Failed to spawn logrotate pre-start process: unable to granpt: Exec format error
init: Failed to spawn dbus pre-start process: unable to granpt: Exec format error
init: Failed to spawn ssh-agent pre-start process: unable to granpt: Exec format error
init: Failed to spawn ssh-agent post-stop process: unable to granpt: Exec format error
init: Failed to spawn xsession-init pre-start process: unable to granpt: Exec format error
```

Xorg.0.log:

```
[  4020.847] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.3
Release Date: 2013-09-12
[  4020.847] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  4020.847] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-51-highbank armv7l Ubuntu
[  4020.847] Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.0.36+ #34 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 17 17:42:40 CST 2014 armv7l
[  4020.847] Kernel command line: console=ttyFIQ0 androidboot.console=ttyFIQ0 init=/init initrd=0x62000000,0x00170000 mtdparts=rk29xxnand:0x00002000@0x00002000(misc),0x00006000@0x00004000(kernel),0x00006000@0x0000a000(boot),0x00010000@0x00010000(recovery),0x00020000@0x00020000(backup),0x00040000@0x00040000(cache),0x001FE000@0x00080000(userdata),0x00002000@0x0027E000(metadata),0x00002000@0x00280000(kpanic),0x00180000@0x00282000(system),0x01000000@0x00402000(uoa),-@0x01402000(user) bootver=2013-12-27#2.10 firmware_ver=4.4.2
[  4020.848] Build Date: 15 October 2013  09:25:29AM
[  4020.848] xorg-server 2:1.14.3-3ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  4020.848] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[  4020.848]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  4020.848] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  4020.849] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jun 19 23:16:02 2014
[  4020.850] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  4020.850] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  4020.851] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  4020.851] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  4020.851] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  4020.852] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[  4020.852] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Screen0".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  4020.852] (**) |-->Input Device "USB Mice"
[  4020.852] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "on"
[  4020.852] (**) Automatically adding devices
[  4020.853] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  4020.853] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  4020.853] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  4020.853]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  4020.853] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  4020.853]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  4020.853] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  4020.853]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  4020.853] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  4020.853]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  4020.853] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  4020.853]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  4020.853] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  4020.853] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  4020.853] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  4020.853] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  4020.853] (WW) Disabling USB Mice
[  4020.853] (II) Loader magic: 0x401deee0
[  4020.853] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  4020.854]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  4020.854]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[  4020.854]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.1
[  4020.854]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[  4020.855] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[  4020.856] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[  4020.856] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[  4020.856] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[  4020.856] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[  4020.856] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[  4020.856] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[  4020.857] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[  4020.869] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  4020.869]    compiled for 1.14.2.901, module version = 0.5.1
[  4020.869]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  4020.869] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  4020.870] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  4020.871] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  4020.871]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  4020.871]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[  4020.871] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  4020.871] Loading extension GLX
[  4020.871] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  4020.871] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  4020.872] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  4020.872]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[  4020.872]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  4020.872]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[  4020.872] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  4020.872] (++) using VT number 7

[  4020.873] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[  4020.873] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  4020.873] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  4020.874] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  4020.874] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  4020.874]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 0.0.2
[  4020.874]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[  4020.875] (II) FBDEV(0): using /dev/graphics/fb2
[  4020.875] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  4020.876] (**) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  4020.876] (==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
[  4020.876] (==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  4020.876] (==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  4020.876] (II) FBDEV(0): hardware: fb2 (video memory: 24576kB)
[  4020.876] (**) FBDEV(0): Option "fbdev" "/dev/graphics/fb2"
[  4020.876] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
[  4020.876] (II) FBDEV(0):     mode "1280x800_60.00" not found
[  4020.876] (II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
[  4020.876] (--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1920x1080 (pitch 1920)
[  4020.876] (**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 148.5 MHz, 67.5 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[  4020.876] (II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 -hsync -vsync -csync (67.5 kHz b)
[  4020.876] (==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[  4020.876] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  4020.877] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  4020.877] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  4020.878] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  4020.878]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[  4020.878]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  4020.878] (**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
[  4020.878] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[  4020.878] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[  4020.878] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[  4020.879] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  4020.879]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.1.0
[  4020.879]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  4020.879] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[  4020.881] (==) FBDEV(0): Backing store disabled
[  4020.881] (==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
[  4020.882] (==) RandR enabled
[  4020.906] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[  4020.910] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[  4020.910] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
[  4020.927] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[  4020.928] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[  4020.998] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[  4023.502] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Also I can launch xfce from the terminal as root fine with `startxfce4`

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Where is `Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: @Braiam added the log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those errors are caused by `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/00upstart`. When you remove it, KDE starts normally.